# Spinner not opening on touch in android

Tags: spinner, android-spinner

I am implementing spinner but when I am touching spinner or on click on that spinner , dropdown is not opening.Spinner array has three values.and parent layout is linear layout 
XML

```
        <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerQuestions"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

        activity :-
        ques =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.select_question);
        ArrayAdapter <String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,     R.layout.spinner_item, ques)
{
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
return v;
}
public View getDropDownView(int position1,  View convertView1,          ViewGroup parent1) {
View v =super.getDropDownView(position1, convertView1, parent1);
return v;
}
};
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerQues.setAdapter(adapter);
spinnerQues.setOnItemSelectedListener(new       AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 questionId = String.valueOf(position);
}
@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved
I am using ActionBar activity.
so that I am getting issue. As I changed ActionBarActivity to activity issue resolved.